# Block Resource in Optaplanner Job scheduling

Tags: resources, scheduling, optaplanner

I've managed to use the Job scheduling example for a project I'm working on. I have an additionnal  constraint I would like to add. Some Resources should be blocked sometimes. For example a Global renewable Resource shouldn't be used between minutes 10 to 20. Is it currently already doable or if not, how can it be done in the score calculation ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom shadow variable listener to predict the starting time of each task.

Then simply have a hard constraint to check that the task won't overlap with its blocks.
Penalize the amount of overlap to avoid a "score trap".

[image: custom shadow variable listener]